# Prevent brakets from resizing

Tags: scaling, resize, physics, braket

I am using the physics package for braket (Dirac) notation. However, some expressions (such as the braket on the right) automatically rescale in the presence of, say, an operator (such as f hat), while others do not (such as the matrix element on the left).

I think this looks a bit ugly, especially when the equations are inline. Rather than making the matrix element bigger, however, I would like the braket to not automatically rescale, and just stay its "normal" size.

[image: problem]

The code is

```
$$ \mel{m}{\hat{f}}{n} = \braket{\hat{f}m}{n} $$
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Did you try smashing the operator?

Comment: @Bernard thank you for your reply. I am not familiar with that macro (or any others really). How would it work in my case? Thank you very much!

Comment: Try `\smash{\braket{\hat{f}m}{n}}`. Other than this, you shouldn't use the plain TeX construct `$$ ... $$` for displayed equations, as it leads to bad spacing. Use `\[ ... \]` instead.

Comment: @Bernard shouldn't it be `\braket{\smash{\hat{f}m}{\smash{n}}`?

Comment: @Skillmon I just tried `\braket{\smash{\hat{f}m}}{n}` and it works (no need to smash the second expression as well). Thank you both!!

Comment: @Skillmon: I think the problem comes from `\hat` since the braket on the left is fine.

Comment: The `physics` package does automatic resizing, which is normally a bad decision to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `\braket*`. Apparently, the author didn't feel the need for specifying explicit size with `\big` or similar commands, like for `\abs`, for instance. Too bad.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{physics}

\begin{document}

\[
\mel{m}{\hat{f}}{n} = \braket*{\hat{f}m}{n}                           
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Don't use `$$`, see [Why is \[ ... \] preferable to $$ ... $$?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503). I don't recommend `physics` either.